# What comand do I enter into my batch file to do this?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I want my batch file to find a string in a file and return it to the next line in my batch file.

How can I do this? I've googled over and over but can't get the specific answer I need with the command to enter into my batch file. So for example

I have a document on desktop and it's called "PhoneNumbers.txt" And I want my batch file to find the string I'm searching for from the file and return it to my batch file for next step of batch file.

Desktop file is called "phonenumbers.txt" and inside is a list of people I know and their phone number. I want my batch file to search for a string say "Amanda P" and return only her number to my batch file so it enters the returned number into the line like

```
ECHO Amanda's phone number is __________
```

Ok so I can't explain it any easier or better so I hope someone understands and can help me with the exacr words to type into my batch file?

Comment: Have you tried FindStr? Type `FindStr /?` into a command prompt for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet should get you started:

```
@echo off
set /p string="Enter search string: " %=%
echo Looking for %string%...
findstr "%string%" phonenumbers.txt
```

In case it is not obvious `%string%` contains the text entered by the user.

How you extract the phone number from the output of `findstr` depends very much on how the line is formatted in the first place. If it is delimited in a sane way, then one possible solution would be to consider using the [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) command.